# Raise Redirect in non-returning function

Tags: python, django, error-handling

I have a function does not return and I want to make a redirection with raising an exception

I have the following code:

```
class RedirectRequired(Exception):

    def __init__(self, url):
        self.url = url
```

And the function

```
 def Foo(x):   
     hede = {'hodo':5}

  try:
         hede.get('hodo').get('hede')
  except AttributeError, e:
         logger.error(e.message)
         raise RedirectRequired('/')
```

But having error `No exception Supplied`. Any ideas for redirecting or raising an exception like below?

Also having the errors.

ERROR Failed to submit message: u'RedirectRequired'
ERROR Failed to submit message: u'RedirectRequired'

Comment: This wouldn't raise an exception because `hede.get` wouldn't raise an `AttributeError`, assuming `hede` is a dictionary or similar

Comment: updated the question. It's just a sample. The process getting the attribute error is much more longer

Comment: And this code is where - in some `View`?

Comment: It doesn't change anything if you're still using `.get`. What you're saying though is that you're guaranteed to be getting an `AttributeError`? Verify that.

Comment: If you're using `.get`, you'll never get an attribute error. `dict.get` returns `None` if no attribute were found.

Comment: >>> hede = {'hodo':5}
>>> hede.get('hodo')
5
>>> hede.get('hodo').get('hede')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'get'
>>>

Comment: Code is in the view and i am getting an Attribute Error, but still unable to redirect

Comment: Ok, you're definitely getting the `AttributeError`, thanks for clarifying

Comment: Any ideas for the case?

Comment: As a side note, unless you really need to work with older Python versions before 2.6, you should use `except AttributeError as e:`, not `except AttributeError, e:`. It avoids various ambiguities, makes linters happy, makes your code forward compatible with Python 3.x, etc.

Comment: The code as edited raises an `IndentationError`. If I fix that, and remove the `logger` call, it raises a `RedirectRequired` exception. Which, as I understand it, is exactly what you wanted. [Run it online and see](http://repl.it/Mbx). If this isn't what you wanted, please explain the desired output. If it is what you wanted, then what's the problem?

Comment: Also, what exactly does this mean: "But having error `No exception Supplied`." Is that some text you grabbed out of a traceback that you haven't shown us? The output of some code you haven't shown us? …?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the constructor of the `RedirectRequired` exception constructs a `RedirectRequired` exception to raise it, which constructs a `RedirectRequired` exception to raise it, which…

Each time through this infinite recursion, you log `e.message`, which will be the same message each time.

After about 1000 of those, you'll hit a `RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded`.

---

Most likely what you really want here is two things: a `RedirectRequired` exception type, and a `Redirector` wrapper class or `redirect` wrapper function that uses it. Like this:

```
class RedirectRequired(Exception):
    pass

class Redirector(object):
    def __init__(self, url):
        self.url = url

        hede = {'hodo':5}
        try:
            hede.get('hodo').get('hede')
        except AttributeError, e:
            logger.error(e.message)
            raise RedirectRequired('/')
```

Now:

```
>>> r = Redirector('abc')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 8, in __init__
__main__.RedirectRequired: /
```

Comment: sorry the question is edited wrongly by TankorSmash. I am correcting it. Thanks for the response though